# Viewing output of --help of any command in one screen

Tags: command-line, output

I am using a virtual machine. It's display is very small.

When I use the following command output goes out of the screen and I cannot view previous content that came from output

```
openssl --help
```

I tried `less`, `more`, redirection but neither worked

```
openssl --help | less
openssl --help | more
openssl --help > output.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openssl` does not have any `--help` argument hence the output of `openssl --help` is being sent to STDERR (file descriptor 2).

When you are using `openssl --help | less`, you are passing STDOUT of `openssl` to STDIN of `less`, as the error message is on STDERR, you can do:

```
openssl --help |& less
```

to pass both STDOUT and STDERR to the STDIN of `less`.

or pass just STDERR:

```
openssl --help 2>&1 >/dev/null | less
```

`2>&1` redirects STDERR to STDOUT, `>/dev/null` sends STDOUT to `/dev/null`.

Again, these are just hacky solutions as there is no option like `--help`, you can instead try

```
man openssl
```

Comment: Actually output for `openssl help` and `man openssl` was different. That's why I used `openssl help`. I would also like to know what `2>&1` means in your answer.

Comment: @afzalex Check my edits